# Displaying combined file size of selected files in Finder

Tags: macos, finder

To find details about a files size, you can right click and select "Get Info":

[image: Get Info Window]

When I select a large number of files, and want to get information about all if them together as a single selection, such as the combined total size, I get the same window for every individual selection, and not a single view for the selection as a whole.

How can I get total file sizes for file/folder selections?

Comment: YEAhhh, Good to see that not only me is getting annoyed by such a stupid design.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Instead of <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to see the info:

[image]

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> does something similar, but gives you a static *Summary Info* window which doesn't update as your selection changes, and you can open multiple windows for different selections, which is handy for comparing groups of synced folders for example.

Comment: Yup, that's it!!

Comment: @daviesgeek I actually didn't know this before. But I always try the option key when looking for new features.

Comment: The Option key really is incredibly undervalued and versatile...  Must re-watch the great Screencast for tips.

Comment: Cmd-Ctrl-I does something similar, but gives you a static "Summary Info" window (doesn't update as selection changes) and you can open multiple windows for different selections. Handy for comparing groups of synced folders.

Comment: Thanks @joelseph I will edit that into the existing answer if it's OK by you - very useful

Comment: @stuffe Fine by me — I guess I could've done that in the first place :)

Comment: Yet another example of where Windows Explorer is far ahead of OSX Finder

Comment: VERY helpful answer.

Comment: Command+apostrophe+[letter I] gets me one info dialog per file. I had a few dozen files selected, but I can take a joke. Still, it would be helpful if you could translate Command-Katakana-Ambiguous into symbols that appear on my (Apple-branded (don't get me started)) keyboard.

Comment: This shouldn't be the answer but one from @Applenut2010. OP says in his post in the first sentence about right clicking. And this answer is about keyboard shortcuts

Answer (score 21):

- Select the files
- right click
- hold alt (notice the menu options change)
- select 'Show Inspector'

Comment: your solution stops halfway: select  'Show Inspector' from the menu then

Comment: @schellmax Then a dialog window showing information of multiple files is being opened, i.e. exactly what OP is asking, there're no other steps. What's the other half of the way supposed to be?

Comment: @DavidFerenczyRogožan trying to remember what i meant here 3 years ago :) - but it seems i was referring to an older version of the answer (see edit history)